# A tag [normalização] está levando a erros de uso?

Tags: debate, tag-específica

Segundo a wiki da tag [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normaliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o):

> A normalização de dados é uma série de passos que se seguem no projeto de um banco de dados, que permitem um armazenamento consistente e um eficiente acesso aos dados em bancos de dados relacionais. Esses passos reduzem a redundância de dados e as chances dos dados se tornarem inconsistentes.
>
> No entanto, muitos SGBDs relacionais não têm separação suficiente entre o projeto lógico da base de dados e a implementação física do banco de dados, e isso tem como consequência que as consultas feitas a um banco de dados totalmente normalizado têm um mau desempenho. Nestes casos, usa-se por vezes a desnormalização para melhorar o desempenho, com o custo de menores garantias de consistência.

A própria wiki leva em consideração que *normalização* se refere a *normalização de dados* no primeiro parágrafo, já no segundo parágrafo fala explicitamente de SGBDs (nas entranhas do primeiro parágrafo bancos de dados relacionais são citados, mas não com ênfase nem força).

Então, basicamente, normalização aqui se refere aos conceitos introduzidos por Codd et al. ao longo do tempo:

- [normalização de bancos de dados, Wikipedia en](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization?wprov=sfti1)
- [1NF de Codd, Wikipedia en](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form?wprov=sfti1)
- tem as outras ***X***-NF na Wikipedia en, mas acho que só linkar a primeira basta, não estou aqui para falar das diversas formas...

E boa parte das perguntas recentes dessa tag tratam desse assunto. Então significa que a tag tem atraído seu público alvo, correto?

Em boa parte sim. Mas normalização tem outros empregos além da normalização da representação dos dados em tabelas...

- Posso tentar normalizar uma URL: [PHP - Função para remover caractere e concatenar strings (URL relativa para absoluta)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114061/64969)
- Normalizar imagens: [Como normalizar varias imagens em matlab](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82442/64969)

  - [Outro exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/138952/64969)
- Normalizar valores antes de enviar a uma função

  - Normalizar strings para deixar em caixa alta: [Capitalizando nomes em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14236/64969)
  - Normalização antes de enviar para função que espera uma string em formato específico: [Obter a última "palavra"  de um PATH com diferentes formatos de URL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/217119/64969)
- Fazer uma normalização estatística para tirar coisas fora do normal...
- Normalizar o *encoding* dos arquivos fonte: [Normalizar encoding de toda uma solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/202141/64969)
- Normalização de nome de arquivo: [Problema ao enviar imagens para uma pasta com nomes acentuados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/155554/64969)
- Normalização de *encoding* de novo: [Como fazer uma busca ignorando acentuação em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3994/64969)
- Normalizar o CSS: [Como resetar a formatação do CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/465/64969)

Então eu acho que a tag é *misleading*... se não ambíguo/possui mais de um significado. Eu proponho renomear o uso corrente da tag para [normalização-banco-de-dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normaliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-banco-de-dados) e tratar essas questões fora do *normal* individualmente.

Answer (score 5):

É possível fazer isto, faz sentido, mas as pessoas continuarão usando errado. Haverá gente usando a nova *tag* para coisas que não são do banco de dados, usarão outras *tags* no caso de ser do banco de dados, criarão a *tag* atual de novo.

A única solução seria a comunidade abraçar a causa de acertar todas *tags*, mas isto não ocorreu. Eu mesmo fazia no começo em quase tudo o que eu podia, mas como eu era quase sozinho e foi ficando muita coisa parei e só arrumo no que eu participo diretamente.

Há pouco mais de 1 ano tive a iniciativa de tentar arrumar *tags*, mas quase não teve aderência.

Comment: Realmente, é um trabalho inglório... Quem sabe uma de cada vez?

Answer (score -3):

Creio que se usada em conjunto com outras tags corretamente, é possível compreender o tipo de normalização de que se trata sem ambiguidades. (Ex.: `normalização` `mysql`, ou `normalização` `css`)

Comment: Mas aí deixa de ser uma tag. O conceito da tag é que ela é autossuficiente, não deveria precisar ser usada com outra tag para passar a fazer sentido